# Excel Pivot Tables - create monthly averages based on slicer date range

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I am building a personal finances worksheet. I have a solid pivot table that shows profit/loss for a given date range.

**Question 1:** How can I show a column (or a separate sheet) that shows monthly averages based on my slider'd date range?

Here's where I have succeeded:
[image: Database Table with accounts, dates, transactions, categories, etc.]
**Database Table with accounts, dates, transactions, categories, etc.**

[image: Pivot Table with date slider, works as expected to generate PL reports on a date range]
**Pivot Table with date slider, works as expected to generate PL reports on a date range**

In the Pivot Table, I included some calculated boxes:

1. Start/End dates pivot table using Min & Max dates in a MMM YYYY format. This is what I used to create the title in yellow.
   (**Question 2:** Can I pull the range title from the slider? E.g. "2022", "Q1 2022")
2. Number of months: `=ROUNDUP(YEARFRAC($E$4,$F$4)*12,0)` This is the number to divide by for monthly averages, obvi.
   (**Question 3:** Again, is there a better way to get this from the pivot table itself?)

Here's what's not working:
[image: Averages based on calculated field]
To get the final column, I used a simple calculated field with `/12`. This works fine for a date range of 12 months, but the other values are useless. I couldn't figure out a way to pull the number of months (from the Slider) into the calculate field.

How can I use the above breakdown, ideally with columns showing Years Quarters Dates (Months) and each value showing a monthly average?

Alternatively, I would be ok with a final column in my original Pivot Table showing these averages, but I can't seem to get that `number of months` variable into a calculated field.

Comment: ,,,, if possible then please share the Sample data or the Worksheet with us,, will help us to try the method genuinely ☺

Comment: Could you provide a simple sample about the data source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both for your help and patience. Sorry for the delay ... I was creating a sample xls file and then started experimenting, and then answered my own question.

To briefly clarify: I was trying to use a pivot table with multiple sets of Values (calculated fields), so that columns would show 1) the total for each month, 2) the monthly average for each quarter, and 3) the monthly average for the year. All grouped into nested columns year, quarter, month, and of course updating as data is added.

I solved this by simply hiding the columns I didn't want to see. Not sure why I didn't think of this sooner. :facepalm: